# Vue-router + firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de login com o vue e o firebase, mas estou com problemas na hora de redirecionar o usuário apos a autenticação:

```
login: function () {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
    (user) => {
      this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'})
    },
    (err) => {
      alert('Error: ' + err.message)
    }
  )
}
```

com o codigo dessa forma ao chamar o metodo login eu recebo o seguinte erro no console:

```
uncaught error during route navigation:
```

seguido de um erro vermelho vazio no console

tentei usar um self no lugar do this, pois o primeiro problema que me veio a cabeça foi esse, o resultado foi:

```
login: function () {
  let self = this
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
    (user) => {
      self.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'})
    },
    (err) => {
      alert('Error: ' + err.message)
    }
  )
}
```

mas o erro continua o mesmo.

alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: quanto ao escopo, a `arrow function` não cria um novo escopo, logo o seu primeiro exemplo está correto. então acredito que o seu problema esteja relacionado com a rota em si, então, se possível compartilhe as suas rotas.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um problema de scopo provavelmente, tenta fazer desta forma:

```
login() {

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
    (user) => {
      this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'})
    },
    (err) => {
      alert('Error: ' + err.message)
    }
  )
}
```

Se o problema pesistir, console esse `this` desta forma:

```
login() {
   console.log(typeof this.$router !== 'undefined');
}
```

Se de `false` , porque você tem um problema de escopo antes deste metódo login. Dai você precisa colocar aqui o código inteiro, para entender melhor seu caso.